# How to move line chart date to the top in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I move the date to the top of the chart.

My chart has negative figure. So the date is in the middle. I want to switch to the top of the chart.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the Label Position to **High**.
[image]

Comment: I'm sure this will help U,,,  get Format Data Labels, select Outside end , then Tick Value From Cells, you may go with Leader Lines too,, remember Options may vary version to version .